# Intellij not recognizing directory as tests

Tags: android, testing, intellij-idea, gradle

I added another source set, and a task of type test that uses that source set. I can execute the task and run the tests fine.

However, Intellij doesn't consider this src/newTests/java as tests. If I 'Mark directory as test sources' in the UI, it will forget it he next time `build.gradle` is synced. How do I make it remember this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        test {
            java.srcDir file('src/newTest/java')
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The issue here is that newTest continues to run under the same Gradle task. It needs to be a different task.